# How to write a Powershell Script with a For-loop using a List of Users to Print Out Active Directory Information

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, scripting, active-directory

So I have a list of users that I need to verify using the RSAT Tools and GetAD-User module within Powershell. As a result, I have determined that the following command will pull out user information, and I am passing another file off for users needing verification. The following command will work and give me user information and see if an email exists:

```bsh
Get-ADUser -filter * -properties EmailAddress -SearchBase 'DC=xxx-xxxx,DC=xxx,DC=xx,DC=us'| select-object Name, EmailAddress | select-string 'doe,john'
```

I therefore tried a loop using the following:

```bsh
cat .\PD.txt | ForEach-Object {Get-ADUser -filter * -properties EmailAddress -SearchBase 'DC=xx-xxxx,DC=xxx,DC=xx,DC=us'| select-object Name, EmailAddress | select-string '$_'}
```

**I have omitted some of the DC infor in terms of the AD names for security reasons.

Inside PD.txt, I would have something like a text files with usernames in Lastname, Firstname per line.
However, nothing prints back in terms of the information. If I did it without the "$_" and the forEach-Object command it would work, but nothing is printing back. Is my forloop wrong?

I tried it a different way and it still didn't work using the apostrphes for the string to pass a different way, by writing it into the `users.txt` file called `Real.txt`. While, I can forloop through it, it doesn't work, when I put in the `GetAD-User` command.
However, I think my for-loop might have something wrong not sure what it is though.

```bsh
PS C:\Users\richard.barrett\Git> cat .\Real.txt | ForEach-Object {echo $_}
'Doe, John'
'Doe, Jane'
```

Comparative For-Loop:

```
PS C:\Users\richard.barrett\Git> cat .\Real.txt | ForEach-Object {Get-ADUser -filter * -properties EmailAddress -SearchBase 'DC=xx-xxxx,DC=xxx,DC=xx,DC=us'| select-object Name, EmailAddress | select-string $_}
```

Comment: the `-Filter` parameter overrides any identity you are sending along. so you SHOULD be getting all the users in the search base. ///// even if you left out the `-Filter` parameter, since you did not give the cmdlet any valid identity parameter OR any that could be mapped to such ... you won't get anything other than errors. PLEASE try reading the docs on the cmdlet you are trying to use. [*grin*]

Comment: I did provide identity parameter, but I omitted them because I didn't want to share that to the public.

Comment: please, NEVER fake the command that you want help with. fake the _values_, yes, but not the actual command. how can anyone help you with a problem when you show something _else_ instead of the problem code? [*grin*]

Comment: Well, for one if you don't have access to my active directory how can I post the exact command and then expect the same output, which is why I put x's in 'DC=xxx-xxxx,DC=xxx,DC=xx,DC=us'. Regardless I found the answer, it was a problem with the way I was passing the variable in Select-String at the end. I should have just put the variable without parenthesis. I will post my answer shortly.

Comment: please, READ what i wrote ... fake the _values_, not the actual _command_. if you show "i turned left" but you actually "turned back" ... how can anyone help you with what did not work as expected? [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out the problem to my issue.
I was not passing the variable correctly into the select-string at the end.
Since I am taking this from a `.txt` file, I decided to set a variable and forgo the for loop just calling the list directly over the file instead of iterating over the `Get-ADUser` command for each user...very slow. As a result, the following worked for me:

```bsh
echo "Users for AD Verification" ; 
echo "============ LIST ============" ; 
cat .\PD.txt | ForEach-Object {echo $_} ; 
echo "============ END LIST ========" ;
echo "Executing Active Directory Verification" ; 
echo "============ PROCESS =========" ;
$list = cat .\PD.txt; 
Get-ADUser -filter * -properties EmailAddress -SearchBase 'DC=del-valle,DC=k12,DC=tx,DC=us'| select-object Name, EmailAddress | select-string $list
echo "============ END PROCESS =====" ;
```

This gave me the list that was defined within the `.\PD.txt`.

Despite my initial hesitance, I have included my Identity OU for users to understand where the OUs should go in the command to pull out users and their email accounts within the AD.

Hopefully this helps someone else, I often get asked to verify users within my Active Directory.

I forgot to add, but the initial issue was with how I was placing the variable into the `select-string` I should not have used apostrophes. Here is the actual command that works as well, but it is slightly longer as it iterates and executes a command for each line...really long.

```bsh
cat .\PD.txt | ForEach-Object {Get-ADUser -filter * -properties EmailAddress -SearchBase 'DC=del-valle,DC=k12,DC=tx,DC=us'| select-object Name, EmailAddress | select-string $_}
```